# V-model binding to generated input text field

Tags: vue.js, axios

Dynamic V-models created during an ajax request doesn't update when I try inputting a value

I'm using vue2.x and axios. I want to get the value set in generated input when user submit the form. I managed to set v-model on this input during ajax request 
I receive this HTLM as response:
`<input type="text" value="" v-model="generatedcode">.` But after submitting the form the value is still empty. Looks like Vue ignore the v-model directive. How can I fix it ?

Here is my code : 
**VUE**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#subcribtionform',
  data: {
    generatedform:'',
    generatedcode:''
  },
  methods:{
    OnSuccess(response){
        this.generatedform = response.data;
    },
   OnclickSub(){
        axios.post('/submitformURL',{
          lastname: this.lastname,
          generatedcode: this.generatedcode,

        })
  }
created: function () {
    axios.get('/generate_inputURL').then(this.OnSuccess);    
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div v-html="generatedform"></div>
```

**GENERATED INPUT**

```
  <input type="text" value="" v-model="generatedcode"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
created: function () {
    axios.get('/generate_inputURL').then(res => this.OnSuccess(res));    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Component data must be function not object. You should be seeing warning about this in console. I guess your component is not reactive data then, which means that is not redrawn after on request done.

```
data(): {
  return {
    generatedform:'',
    generatedcode:''
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I'm not using a component

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you want to change the vue-app template using  v-html attr - I think this is not possible. While mounting the application, the template compiles into render function, so your trick does not make any sense. You can try to do the following:

1. Construct the  template (using html recieved from server as you want ) as string or as hidden el in the DOM
2. Set it in your app object - template:your_html_template
3. Create vue app